# Call foo if true else bar

Tags: javascript

Just out of curiosity, anything like this possible in JavaScript ?

```
var c, flag = true;
c = Math.(flag ? min : max)(a, b); // c = flag ? Math.min(a, b) : Math.max(a, b);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re almost right. But it won’t work because what are `min` and `max` in that context referring to?

You either have to specify a qualified identifier:

```
(flag ? Math.min : Math.max)(a, b)
```

Or you use the bracket syntax and just specify the property’s identifier name:

```
Math[flag ? "min" : "max"](a, b)
```

Comment: @KennyTM: You were only one post ID after mine. :)

Comment: The bracket syntax is very interesting. Thanks.